# How can I put the text from the TextFields in a TableView(javafx)?

Tags: java, javafx, tableview

This is the class MenuItem that I use to create an object which would be displayed in the tableview.

```
@XmlRootElement
public class MenuItem {

    final ObservableList<MenuItem> menuI = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    public SimpleStringProperty description;
    public SimpleDoubleProperty price;
    public SimpleStringProperty picturePath;
    public ArrayList<String> variant = new ArrayList<>();

    public ArrayList<String> getVariant() {

        return variant;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public void setVariant(ArrayList<String> variant) {
        this.variant = variant;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description.get();
    }

    @XmlElement
    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description.set(description);
    }

    public Double getPrice() {
        return price.get();
    }

    /**
     * Aceasta functie seteaaza pretul meniului
     *
     * @param price -acesta este pretul pe care il setam
     */
    @XmlElement
    public void setPrice(Double price) {
        this.price.set(price);
    }

    public String getPicturePath() {
        return picturePath.get();
    }

    @XmlElement
    public void setPicturePath(String picturePath) {
        this.picturePath.set(picturePath);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return description + " " + price + " " + variant;
    }

}
```

And I tried something like this but without any result.

```
@FXML
private TableView<MenuItem> tableOfMenuItems;

@FXML
private TableColumn<MenuItem, String> variantCol, descriptionCol, priceCol;

ObservableList<MenuItem> list = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

variantCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("variant"));
descriptionCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("description"));
priceCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>(("price")));

list.add(menuItem);
tableOfMenuItems.setItems(list);
```

Comment: Of course there is no result. The controller doesn't even compile. You cannot simply put statements other than field initialisations in a class body outside of method bodys/initializers. Furthermore not declaring `menuItem` should be a problem too. Furthermore only the description property is of type `String`. Using the wrong type parameters for `TableColumn` could easily result in exceptions at runtime.

Comment: I did the changes but without any result. I have an error. NullPointerException and I don't understand why.